# CoreData NSPredicate: fetch object with UUID that is contained within a Set<UUID>

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, foundation

I have a CoreData entity with an identifier of type UUID, declared as: `@NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?` .

I want to create a fetch request that would return all entities for which the identifier (`uuid`) is contained within a Set (or array) of UUIDs. Here's my function so far:

```
    func delete(_ identifiers: Set<UUID>) {
        let idsToFetch = positionIDs.map { $0 as NSUUID }
        // idsToFetch is of type Array<NSUUID>

        let fetchRequest = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@", #keyPath(MyEntity.uuid), idsToFetch)
        
        do {
            let result = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            for object in result {
                mainContext.delete(object)
            }
        } catch {
            // error management out of scope of this question
            return
        }
    }
```

I saw other answers and [this post](https://jisyed.github.io/blog/2018/using-uuids-in-predicates-to-fetch-core-data-entities/) that suggest to cast each element to CArgVar, but [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/60353) suggests to use Foundation bridging equivalent instead. Either way don't return any result.

I made sure the elements I'm fetching do exist, by opening the .sql file in an editor. I can confirm that the UUID is written, but shows up as *blob*.

Thank you for any insight

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but the code predicate worked fine for me so the expected objects got deleted. I used the Set (`identifiers`) in the predicate and not an NSUUID array but that is the only difference. I think there is something else that is the issue here, one way forward is to check what the actual SQL query is but turning on Core Data debugging, add the following launch argument to your scheme `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` (it can be up to 4 if you want even more detail)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did just that, with `SQLDebug 4`. It returned this: ```CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement on entity 'Entity' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZINDEX, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZUUID FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZUUID IN  (?)  ' returned 0 rows
CoreData: annotation:  with values: (
)``` 
I don't know why I don't see values here, though. A previous log indicated that the parameter was binded: `CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 35AD7A3A-72DB-47BE-B893-58E3581033BA`.

Comment: That looks fine so I think the issue is not with the predicate but something else

Comment: You are correct! I just saw the issue, it was indeed somewhere else (in translating NSManagedObject to Model). Thank you so much for your eyes and your input!